# ES6 default values for only some of params object

Tags: ecmascript-6

Given a function like the following, what is the correct syntax to use in order to be able to call `showToast({ text: "some text"})` and still get the default values for `params.autoHide` and `params.action` ?

```
function showToast (params = {text: 'Something happened!', autoHide: false, action: 'CLOSE'}) {
    //noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
    const toast = $mdToast.simple()
        .textContent(params.text)
        .position('top right')
    ;

    if (!params.autoHide) {
        toast.hideDelay(false);
    }
    if (params.action) {
        //noinspection JSValidateTypes
        toast.action(params.action); // label for close btn
    }

    $mdToast.show(toast);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object destructuring in the argument list too. The only thing that changes is you must not access the parameters through the `params` object:

```js
function foo({text = "Hi", autoHide = false, action = "CLOSE"} = {}) {
  console.log(text + " " + autoHide + " " + action)
}

foo({text: "asd"});
```

See [babel/repl](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20foo(%7Btext%20%3D%20%22Hi%22%2C%20autoHide%20%3D%20false%2C%20action%20%3D%20%22CLOSE%22%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(text%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20autoHide%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20action)%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo(%7Btext%3A%20%22asd%22%7D)%3B%0A).

Notice the `= {}` default value for the destructuring object. This makes it possible to call the function without a single parameter: `foo();`.

Comment: Upvote for putting me in my place and teaching me a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter object destructuring to achieve this:

```
function showToast({text = 'Something happened!', autoHide = false, action = 'CLOSE'} = {}) {
    //noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
    const toast = $mdToast.simple().textContent(text).position('top right');

    if (!autoHide) {
        toast.hideDelay(false);
    }
    if (action) {
        //noinspection JSValidateTypes
        toast.action(action); // label for close btn
    }

    $mdToast.show(toast);
}

showToast({ text: "some text" }) // defaults autoHide to false, action to 'CLOSE'
```

See ["Setting a function parameter's default value"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).